# Cannot refactor after xcode 4.6 (xcode crash) for One Project (other project is doing fine)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

What I did:

I was refactoring when  xcode seems was trying to download something 10.8x document or what. How do I resume what ever xcode hasn't download?

I already clean projects, and clean snapshot, delete snapshot directory.

This one project make xcode hang when trying to refactor. The other projects do not have this problem.

If I want to reinstall xcode do I have to redownload it?
This is the error message

```
Process:         Xcode [8490]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.6 (2066)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-2066000000000000~3
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 13668903
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [144]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-02-07 13:16:52.813 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          376575 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           8
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  6013 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      1CBC3344-3A0F-4006-F51E-8FF9902D7CC5

Crashed Thread:  8  Dispatch queue: Refactoring parser lock

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000040

VM Regions Near 0x40:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010fb35000-000000010fb38000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H127
objc[8490]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df3686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df2c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92683803 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92688ee6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff926886b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff90cac0a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff90cabe42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff90cabcd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9573c613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9573bed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff95733283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff956d7cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
12  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010fb36b6f 0x10fb35000 + 7023
13  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010fb36b00 0x10fb35000 + 6912

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df5d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d5d0dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d5d09ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df56d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0aceec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0accb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b097171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df3686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df2c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92683803 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92688ee6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff926886b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d175586 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d1d3612 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0aa742 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b097181 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df3686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df2c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92683803 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92688ee6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff926886b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x0000000117836593 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 229
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d1d3612 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0aa742 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b097181 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df5322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff926c84e6 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0aa742 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b097181 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df56d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0aceec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0accb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b097171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96df56d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0aceec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b0accb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b097171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: Refactoring parser lock
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8b098650 strlen + 16
1   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224bf501 Devkit::Cpp::tmpcat(char const*) + 33
2   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d8c05 Devkit::Cpp::convertTokensToString(Devkit::Token*, Devkit::Token*, Devkit::TokenBuffer*, Devkit::TokenBuffer*, bool) + 275
3   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d515b Devkit::Cpp::expand(Devkit::Token*, Devkit::Macro*, Devkit::TokenBufferStream*) + 849
4   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224cb105 Devkit::Cpp::expandMacro2Buffer(Devkit::Token*, Devkit::Macro*, Devkit::TokenBufferStream*) + 291
5   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224caf5b Devkit::Cpp::macro_expand(Devkit::Token*, Devkit::Macro*) + 33
6   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c314d Devkit::Cpp::nextToken0() + 243
7   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c3044 Devkit::Cpp::nextToken() + 14
8   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c2fd9 Devkit::ObjcParse::nextToken() + 19
9   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d2dce Devkit::ObjcParse::statement() + 662
10  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d79c9 Devkit::ObjcParse::selectionStatement() + 301
11  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d2aeb Devkit::ObjcParse::statementList(objc_object*) + 37
12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d28ab Devkit::ObjcParse::compoundStatement(objc_object*) + 131
13  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224f55fa Devkit::ObjcParse::blockLiteralExpression() + 312
14  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7cdb Devkit::ObjcParse::postfix() + 397
15  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7634 Devkit::ObjcParse::multiplicative() + 22
16  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c75c6 Devkit::ObjcParse::additive() + 22
17  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7558 Devkit::ObjcParse::shift() + 22
18  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c74ea Devkit::ObjcParse::relational() + 22
19  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c747c Devkit::ObjcParse::equality() + 22
20  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c740e Devkit::ObjcParse::bitwiseAnd() + 22
21  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c73a2 Devkit::ObjcParse::bitwiseExclusiveOr() + 22
22  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7336 Devkit::ObjcParse::bitwiseInclusiveOr() + 22
23  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c72ca Devkit::ObjcParse::logicalAnd() + 22
24  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c725e Devkit::ObjcParse::logicalOr() + 22
25  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c71d2 Devkit::ObjcParse::conditional() + 18
26  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224cadde Devkit::ObjcParse::assignment() + 18
27  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224e21ab Devkit::ObjcParse::objcKeywordList(objc_object*) + 93
28  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224e1f30 Devkit::ObjcParse::objcMessageExpression() + 244
29  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7cdb Devkit::ObjcParse::postfix() + 397
30  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7634 Devkit::ObjcParse::multiplicative() + 22
31  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c75c6 Devkit::ObjcParse::additive() + 22
32  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7558 Devkit::ObjcParse::shift() + 22
33  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c74ea Devkit::ObjcParse::relational() + 22
34  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c747c Devkit::ObjcParse::equality() + 22
35  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c740e Devkit::ObjcParse::bitwiseAnd() + 22
36  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c73a2 Devkit::ObjcParse::bitwiseExclusiveOr() + 22
37  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c7336 Devkit::ObjcParse::bitwiseInclusiveOr() + 22
38  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c72ca Devkit::ObjcParse::logicalAnd() + 22
39  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c725e Devkit::ObjcParse::logicalOr() + 22
40  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224c71d2 Devkit::ObjcParse::conditional() + 18
41  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224cadde Devkit::ObjcParse::assignment() + 18
42  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224cad83 Devkit::ObjcParse::expression() + 65
43  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d7ced Devkit::ObjcParse::expressionStatement() + 41
44  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d2b0f Devkit::ObjcParse::statementList(objc_object*) + 73
45  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224d28ab Devkit::ObjcParse::compoundStatement(objc_object*) + 131
46  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224e18d0 Devkit::ObjcParse::objcMethodDefinition() + 352
47  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224cbec0 Devkit::ObjcParse::externalDeclaration() + 208
48  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224cbdc8 Devkit::ObjcParse::translationUnit() + 92
49  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224ba940 -[DevkitEntireProject parseOneCompilationUnit:] + 2633
50  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x00000001224b9ea3 -[DevkitParser parseOneCompilationUnit:buildSettings:] + 170
51  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring   0x0000000122524ab6 __76-[DevkitRefactoringTransformation parseCompilationUnit:buildSettings:error:]_block_invoke + 84

ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=289.4M resident=167.0M(58%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=122.4M(42%)
Writable regions: Total=17.4G written=90.9M(1%) resident=270.5M(2%) swapped_out=584K(0%) unallocated=17.1G(98%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
ATS (font support)                   31.9M
ATS (font support) (reserved)           4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CG backing stores                    16.2M
CG image                              184K
CG raster data                        420K
CG shared images                     1248K
CoreAnimation                         320K
CoreImage                              24K
CoreServices                         3776K
IOKit                                11.6M
IOKit (reserved)                      512K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
JS JIT generated code               128.0M
JS JIT generated code (reserved)    896.0M        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
JS VM register file                  4096K
JS garbage collector                  644K
MALLOC                              503.5M
MALLOC (reserved)                    15.8G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC guard page                     112K
Memory tag=240                          4K
Memory tag=242                         12K
Memory tag=243                          4K
Memory tag=249                        156K
Memory tag=251                         64K
OpenCL                                 60K
OpenGL GLSL                          1024K
SQLite page cache                    18.0M
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                16.7M
VM_ALLOCATE                          17.9M
__DATA                               30.3M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           70.3M
__TEXT                              219.2M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         113.8M
shared memory                        18.7M
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                17.9G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space        1.2G

Model: iMac11,2, BootROM IM112.0057.B01, 2 processors, Intel Core i3, 3.06 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 1.64f5
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4670, ATI Radeon HD 4670, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.70.23-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD5000AAKS-40V6A0, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-STDVDRW  GA32N
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Expansion, 0x0bc2  (Seagate LLC), 0x2312, 0xfd130000 / 5
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8502, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: USB-compliant keyboard, 0x0518  (EzKEY Corp.), 0x0001, 0xfa130000 / 5
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 6
```

Other people with similar problem:

http://osdir.com/ml/general/2013-02/msg06015.html

Comment: I can refactor other projects

Comment: have you tried going to the organizer, closing the project and all of its windows, and then deleting derived data from the organizer?  this is a cache of information that may be corrupting what you're working with to a greater degree than clean can take care of.  you'll have to re-open your project from outside the organizer (double-click in finder or Cmd-O within Xcode), and it will have to re-build all of its indexes, etc.

Comment: I think I have unless I did something different. How to do that exactly? If I close all xcode project I can't go to oranizer.

Comment: I deleted everything deleteable in organizer. Still same problem.

Comment: Have you tried going back to previous revisions of the code and refactor from there?

Comment: Depending on the size of your project it might be difficult, but have you tried to find the part of your code, where the thing crashes based on the crash log? Maybe there is a construction the parser can not handle for some reason.

As for the download:
You can restart it from the preference pane in the downloads section.

Comment: I have had similar problems with a couple of projects that are fairly large and include libraries/projects that are built along with the main target.  I get the crashes intermittently while it is searching for code that will be affected by the refactor.  Is that *when* your crash occured?  And what is the relative size of your project?

Comment: Project is very large. This bug start happen weeks ago. So there is no way I go back to the old version. Shearer is right. It crash when searching for code. Perhaps a part of that code is not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holy Cow! This was hard to track down. I was having the same problem, but I managed to track it down (at least for me).

The crash occurs when you Refactor > Rename… and your source has a macro which includes a @ literal construct.

Crash Example 1:

```
STAssertEqualObjects([currencyFormatter numberFromString:@" $100. "], @100.00, nil);
STAssertEqualObjects([currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"100"], @100.00, nil);
```

Fixed with:

```
NSNumber *x100_00 = @100.00;
STAssertEqualObjects([currencyFormatter numberFromString:@" $100. "],x100_00, nil);
STAssertEqualObjects([currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"100"], x100_00, nil);
```

Crash Example 2:

```
STAssertEqualObjects(isActive, @YES, nil);
```

Fixed with: success

```
NSNumber *xYES = @YES;
STAssertEqualObjects(isActive, xYES, nil);
```

Crash Example 3:

```
NSParameterAssert(([@[@"Option 1", @"Option 2"] containsObject:shareType]));
```

Fixed with:

```
- (NSArray *)GMS_shareTypes
{
    return @[@"Option 1", @"Option 2"];
}

…

NSParameterAssert([self.GMS_shareTypes containsObject:shareType]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, I think realistically you should try to track down exactly which part of code causes the refactor to fail. Be methodical, and try to establish where the issue lies. At that point, you can begin working out what caused it.

When I've had refactoring issues in the past, a full scrub has sorted it out (clearing DerivedData may also help if you've not done that yet).

Comment: If it helps tracking it down, it looks from the backtrace that the crash is happening expanding a macro inside of a block literal.

Comment: Actually all variables cannot be refactored.

Comment: Comment out code, etc. Break it apart, and fix individual files one at a time to isolate the issue.

Comment: There are hundreds of file. What makes you think it's macro anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to solve but here is some clues from the crash report:

- Seems that you have a **macro** that expands to something that is not correctly parsed. I mean it generates a wrong token (infinite length for example)
- Looks it is somewhere **after complex bitwise logics and shift statements**
- maybe inside a **block**.

Could you check your macro:

- remove it
- or replace by inline
- or sometime just copy paste it or rewrite it (wrong invisible character).

That may fix your pb.
Tell me.

Comment: Check what? The whole program compile just fine. The program is so big.

Comment: I can't possibly check every variable or every block or every definition. There are so many of it.

Comment: What kind of refactoring stuff causes the crash (rename, extracts, move super...?)

Comment: rename. I only use rename.